# Iterate through table fields, and send values by email

Tags: javascript, php, loops, html-table, field

I have table like this:

```
<tr class="product">
 <td><input class ="parts" id="tf1" type="text" style="width:327px"/></td>
 <td><input class ="parts" id="tf2" type="text" style="width:51px";"/></td>
 <td><input class ="parts" id="tf3" type="text" style="width:144px";"/></td>
 <td><input class ="parts" id="tf4" type="text" style="width:64px";"/></td>
 <td><input class ="parts" id="tf5" type="text" style="width:81px";"/></td>
 <td><input class ="parts" id="tf6" type="text" style="width:12px";"/></td>
 <td><input class ="parts" id="tf7" type="text" style="width:21px";"/></td>
 <td><input class ="parts" id="tf8" type="text" style="width:22px";"/></td>
 <td><input class ="parts" id="tf9" type="text" style="width:22px";"/></td>
 <td><input class ="parts" id="tf10" type="text" style="width:60px";"/></td>
 <td><input class ="parts" id="tf11" type="text" style="width:35px";"/></td>
 <td><input class ="parts" id="tf12" type="text" style="width:41px";"/></td>
 <td><input class ="parts" id="tf13" type="text" style="width:50px";"/></td>
 <td><input class ="parts" id="tf14" type="text" style="width:44px";"/></td>
 <td><input type="button" class="addRow" value="Add"/></td>
 <td><input type="button" class="delRow" value="Delete"/></td>
</tr>
```

I want to iterate trough every field of table row, and mark result and send it with php mail to email address. I think it is fairly simple, but it somehow dont work. 
I tried with this function:

```
function fill(){
var value = $find.("tr.product.input.parts").html();
return value;
}
```

Comment: how do you intend to send/process these info? do you want to use js only? or do you want to use php?

Comment: I was thinking to put variable in invisible text field, and then via POST method send it to php, and then format it and email it...

Comment: The html() method receives only the first element. It does not iterate. You may use for each.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your addRow and delRow buttons are working since you didn't mentioned anything about it:

Change your input name to array instead. so instead of

```
<td><input class ="parts" id="tf1" type="text" style="width:327px"/></td>
<td><input class ="parts" id="tf2" type="text" style="width:51px"/></td>
<td><input class ="parts" id="tf3" type="text" style="width:144px"/></td>
```

You should use

```
<td><input class ="parts" id="tf1" name="tf[]" type="text" style="width:327px"/></td>
<td><input class ="parts" id="tf2" name="tf[]" type="text" style="width:51px"/></td>
<td><input class ="parts" id="tf3" name="tf[]" type="text" style="width:144px"/></td>
```

When processing with PHP, all the values will be in $_POST['tf'] in array form, starting from index 0. With this you can loop through and process it and send it via email.

Anyway, I'm wondering why your text fields have different width and style="width:327px";" is a wrong markup.

Comment: So I should use id as array? And yes my add and delete buttons are working. And I use different width because I need different sizes of fields. And ---;"--- is mistake, removed...

Comment: Posting it in array is easier to do post-processing since there's no fixed number of inputs.